# Is there anyway that I can convert multiple psd files to multiple pdf files?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have 200 psd files, and I want to convert them to 200 separated pdf files. Is there anyway I can do that? I have tried to search on google, all the tutorials are about how to convert and combine psd files into one multi-page pdf.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an action in the set of Default Actions called "Save as Photoshop PDF."

1. Put all of the PSD files you want to convert in a folder with nothing else in it.
   Start Photoshop.
2. Go to File > Automate > Batch
3. Find the action and set the source to the appropriate folder
4. Set the destination to the desired folder
5. Add a serial number or letter after the document name (i.e. Document Name, Serial Number, extension)
6. Click OK

If you don't want to confirm each file name, you'll have to write a script instead using app.displayDialogs (at least that's the way I did it).

Answer (score 0):

I just write an script to convert psd files to separated pdf files.

```
// input files location
var inputFolder = Folder.selectDialog("Choose the folder that contains psd files");
var inputFiles = inputFolder.getFiles("*.psd");

// output files location
var outputFolder = Folder.selectDialog("Choose the folder to save files to");

// SET the options for saving pdf files
var PDFOptions = new PDFSaveOptions();
PDFOptions.PDFCompatibility = PDFCompatibility.PDF13


for(var i = 0; i<inputFiles.length; i++){
    open(inputFiles[i]);
    app.activeDocument.saveAs(
    new File(outputFolder + "/" + inputFiles[i].name + ".pdf"),
    PDFOptions
    );
    app.activeDocument.close();
    // alert(inputFiles[i].name)
}
alert("All psd Files has been converted to PDF!");
```